Error with path for ARM toolchain while using Segger Embedded Studio
Recently I had a strange anomaly, where I build the project twice in a row and on the second build it seems that the path to the ARM toolchain has broken. I'm confused because I haven't changed anything for that to happen. The error is the following:
Error starting process C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10\bin/cc1
The /cc1 comes out of nowhere because the path to the toolchain is:
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10\arm-none-eabi\bin

This is the output of Segger:

This is the project options, as you can see, the path is the correct one:

I want to know if someone had an issue with this and how did they fix it?
It seems to me that this is a bug. I have it in setup up in the system's PATH, so corrupted installation is out of the question:

I re-added the toolchain directory, but that doesn't fix the problem.
